# Issue when loading a page in a WebView control

Tags: java, android, image

I have a problem with the code shown below. It will use an image when the `WebView` loads.

[View this first.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/7UGXq.png)

```
public class Vote extends Activity {

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.vote);

        String url = "http://minecraftpocket-servers.com/server/30206/vote/";
        WebView view = (WebView) this.findViewById(R.id.webView);

        view.getSettings().setJavaScriptEnabled(true);
        view.loadUrl(url);
            }
    @Override
    public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
        // Inflate the menu; this adds items to the action bar if it is present.
        getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.main, menu);
        return true;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
        // Handle action bar item clicks here. The action bar will
        // automatically handle clicks on the Home/Up button, so long
        // as you specify a parent activity in AndroidManifest.xml.
        int id = item.getItemId();

        //noinspection SimplifiableIfStatement
        if (id == R.id.action_settings) {
            return true;
        }

        return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
    }
}
```

Comment: What issue you are facing?

Comment: like this http://i.stack.imgur.com/7UGXq.png

Comment: You wanna load image while the webview is loading the data?

Comment: yes that what i need

Answer (score 0):

Please try this in onCreate method -

```
    final AlertDialog alertDialog = new AlertDialog.Builder(this).create();

  final  ProgressDialog progressBar = ProgressDialog.show(Vote.this, "Showing ProgressDialog", "Loading...");

    view.setWebViewClient(new WebViewClient() {
        public boolean shouldOverrideUrlLoading(WebView view, String url) {
            Log.i(TAG, "Processing webview url click...");
            view.loadUrl(url);
            return true; 
        } 

        public void onPageFinished(WebView view, String url) {
            Log.i(TAG, "Finished loading URL: " + url);
            if (progressBar.isShowing()) {
                progressBar.dismiss();
            } 
        } 

        public void onReceivedError(WebView view, int errorCode, String description, String failingUrl) {
            Log.e(TAG, "Error: " + description);
            Toast.makeText(Main.this, "Oh no! " + description, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            alertDialog.setTitle("Error");
            alertDialog.setMessage(description);
            alertDialog.setButton("OK", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
                public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) {
                    return; 
                } 
            }); 
            alertDialog.show();
        } 
    }); 
    webview.loadUrl(url);
```

Comment: replace Main with your Class Name  and also see my edits.

Comment: Your current class name is Vote so please use Vote instead of Main

Comment: why sorry i am so noob

Comment: Edited your 1st Post

Comment: Error:(32, 23) error: cannot find symbol variable TAG

Comment: private static final String TAG = "Main";

define this variable

Comment: Error:(41, 21) error: local variable progressBar is accessed from within inner class; needs to be declared final

Comment: Error:(61, 32) error: cannot find symbol class Main

Comment: replace Main.this  with Vote.this.